# Sort list of tuples by value Python

Tags: python

I've got a list of tuples as the example:

```
result = [(1, 6.06), (2, 6.23), (3, 7.03), (4, 6.88), (5, 6.43), (6, 6.57)]
```

How can I sort the list by value in descending order?

Comment: by the second parameter !! sorry !!

Comment: Assuming those tuples are key-value pairs, is there a reason you don't have a `dict` here? (Or, since the keys are just small integers that are dense except for missing 0, maybe even a `list`?)

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like:

```
result.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

Or some prefer

```
from operator import itemgetter
result.sort(key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

...

or perhaps just:

```
result.sort(reverse=True)
```

depending on what you mean by `value`.

If you don't want to sort the list in place, you can always use `sorted` in much the same way.  Of course, the canonical guide to how to sort in python is found at the following link: ["Sorting Mini-HOW TO"](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

Comment: Great answer. But it might be worth adding a link to the [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, but instead of a `lambda` you can use [`operator.itemgetter(1)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
result.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```